# Can interface type variable call methods from that interface in a class that doesn’t implement it?

Tags: java, interface

I'm trying to understand this just for my own knowledge. Here is a broken down version of my code:

```java
interface ILightningPhone {
    void recharge();
    void useLightning();
}

interface IMicroUsbPhone {
    void recharge();
    void useMicroUsb();
}

class LightningToMicroUsbAdapter implements IMicroUsbPhone {
    private final ILightningPhone lightningPhone;

    public LightningToMicroUsbAdapter(ILightningPhone lightningPhone) {
        this.lightningPhone = lightningPhone;
    }

    @Override
    public void useMicroUsb() {
        System.out.println("MicroUsb connected");
        lightningPhone.useLightning();
    }

    @Override
    public void recharge() {
        lightningPhone.recharge();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand interfaces and I just need an explanation on the following:

1. I notice that a variable `private final ILightningPhone lightningPhone;` is declared within a class of type `ILightningPhone` interface. but this class doesn't implement that interface. How is it able to do this?
2. Next I notice that in the following method:

   ```
   public void useMicroUsb() {
       System.out.println("MicroUsb connected");
       lightningPhone.useLightning();
   ```

   the variable `lightningPhone` is able to call the `useLightning()` method from the `ILightningPhone` interface. Even though the `ILightningPhone` interface is not implemented in the class `LightningToMicroUsbAdapter`. Why is it able to do this?

Overall, I'm just trying to understand why we are able to create a variable of a interface type in a class that doesn't implement that interface? And why when declaring that variable of that interface type are we able to use the methods from that interface in a class that doesn't implement that interface?

Here is the full code if needed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: You don't have to *be* a phone to *have* a phone.

Comment: You are confused because this example is confusing! If your `LightningToMicroUsbAdapter` was just a `Person` class (without an interface) It would be easier to understand how Person could call the methods of ILightningPhone on the ILightingPhone

Comment: You may want to revisit the basics of Java. I'm not sure what thinking process can even lead to a theory that a type that doesn't implement X cannot have fields of type X or call methods on that field. Composition is one of the fundamentals of object oriented programming.

Comment: Think about if you swapped `private final ILightningPhone lightningPhone;` with `private final String s;`. You can still call `s.length()` even though `LightningToMicroUsbAdapter ` doesn't implement `CharSequence`

Answer (score 0):

The `LightningToMicroUsbAdapter` class (or any class for that matter) can have any type of member - be it a `String`, a `List`, or even a `ILightningPhone`. Having a members is a "hasA" relationship, not an "isA" relationship.

Since the `lightningPhone` **is** an instance of `ILightningPhone`, it can call the `useLightning` method defined by that interface.